# How can I convert the output from a ostream_iterator to a string?

Tags: c++, string, iterator, ostream

I am implementing a toString method in C++ primarily using the ostream_iterator.

```
std::ostream_iterator<int> output(std::cout, " ");
```

After printing to the console, however, I wish to return the output of the ostream_iterator as a string. Is this direct conversion possible?

Comment: No, you would need to do something like output to a stringstream instead of `cout`

Comment: Yes.  Sample code in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this direct conversion possible?

I think, no, because `ostream_iterator` is used to send data to stream one way, so if the destination is `std::cout` you cannot use `ostream_iterator` to get data back.

But you can use some other destination, e.g. `ostringstream` object, and then use it for both output through `cout` and use again as you like.

Consider simple example:

```cpp
    std::stringstream buff;
    std::ostream_iterator<int> output(buff, " ");
    std::istringstream str("10 3 ABC 7 1");
    // just copy only first integer values from str (stop on the first non-integer)
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(str), std::istream_iterator<int>(), output);
    // output as a string to std output
    std::cout << buff.str() << std::endl;
    // do something else
    buff.seekp(0, std::ios::end);
    std::cout << "String size is " << buff.tellp() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, just replace cout with stringstream and you can create string from it.

```
std::stringstream ss; // #include <sstream>
std::ostream_iterator<int> output(ss, " ");
std::string s(ss.str());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a string-like object that uses the `std::ostream` interface rather than the STL container interface, that’s `std::stringstream`, or the deprecated `std::strstream`  The closest thing to a generic wrapper that turns anything that can be serialized with `cout <<` into a `std::string` would be to write to a `std::stringstream` and then read the data back out.  This will end up making at least one expensive copy, however.  Here’s an implementation:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using isit = std::istream_iterator<char>;

template <typename T> std::string to_string(const T& x)
// Must be able to print a T with std::ostream::operator<<.
{
  std::stringstream buffer;
  buffer << x;

  const isit begin(buffer);     // The start of the stream object. 
  static const isit end;        // Default object is the end-of-stream iterator.

  return std::string( begin, end );
}

int main(void)
{
  const std::string output_string = to_string("Testing:") + " " +
    to_string(1) + ", " + to_string(2ULL) + ", " + to_string(3.0) +
    to_string('.');

  cout << output_string << endl;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You can use a `std::ostream_iterator<char>` to write to a `std::stringstream`, rather than `<<`, and then a `std::istream_iterator<char>` as shown to copy from that to a string.

You can write data from a `std::istream` to a `std::string` with a `std::istream_iterator`.  Sort of.  The formatting can be wonky.

If you want to read data from a `std::string` using an iterator, its iterator type is `std::string::iterator` and an iterator to the front of the string is `s.begin()`, like other STL containers.

If you just have a bunch of data stored in memory that you want to send to both an output iterator and a string, you can use one of its other constructors.